# How to get img url and alt text from CDATA

Tags: html, css, swift, tags

How to get img url and alt text from this code:

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
<img src="http://images.one.co.il/images/d/dmain/small/gg1240016.gif" hspace="10px" width="85px" height="64px" align="right" alt="איברהים אפלאיי מול אריק למאלה (רויטרס)" />שער מהיר של קיין (10) העלה את התרנגולים ליתרון. כעת, הפער מהמוליכה, לסטר, עומד על חמש נקודות בלבד. החלוץ חלף על פני ורדי בטבלת מלך השערים
]]>
</description>
```

I tried to use this:

```
class Descrition: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate{

    var itemsStarted=false;
    var inDescription=false;
    var inImg=false;
    var urls:[String]=[];

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
        if elementName=="item"{
            itemsStarted=true;
        }
        if itemsStarted&&elementName=="description"{
            inDescription=true;
        }
        if inDescription&&elementName=="img"{
            inImg=true;
            urls.append(attributeDict["alt"]!);
        }
    }
    //content inside each element
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        if inImg{
            urls.append(string);
        }
    }
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if elementName=="img"{
            inImg=false;
        }
    }
}
```

and error.